# How can I check if animation has ended playing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
    {
        if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Stand Up"))
        {
            camera.rotation = medeaHead.rotation;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it's getting to the inside line :

```
camera.rotation = medeaHead.rotation;
```

before even the animation start playing.

Comment: We're might need some more information on your animator and its states to answer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use animation events so that you can put a function at any frame of the animation you want. Here is the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html) for animation events, you can also find many tutorials on youtube.